# How to merge irregular object

Tags: javascript, object

I wanna merge 2 objects.

One object is the default form.

```
let data = {
  weight: '',
  DOB: '',
  gender: '',
}
```

The other is irregular like below that

```
let temp1 = {
   weight: '19.2',
}

let temp2 = {
   DOB: '1992-11',
}

let temp3 = {
   DOB: '1992-11',
   gender: 'Male',
}

let temp4 = undefined;
```

If I merge `data` and `temp1`, the result should be

```
let data = {
  weight: '19.2',
  DOB: '',
  gender: ''
}
```

If I merge `data` and `temp3`, the result should be

```
let data = {
  weight: '',
  DOB: '1992-11',
  gender: 'Male',
}
```

If I merge `data` and `temp4`, the result should be

```
let data = {
  weight: '',
  DOB: '',
  gender: ''
}
```

Give me some advice to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, you can't merge that way. You gotta set those values to undefined, right?

Comment: If your default object always has the 3 keys, why not just check each different object for those properties? If they exist, take them, if not, ignore.

Comment: @tomerpacific I can check there's existing or not, but I need to preserve the default object form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign()`:

```
let data = {
  weight: '',
  DOB: '',
  gender: '',
}


let temp3 = {
   DOB: '1992-11',
   gender: 'Male',
}

data = Object.assign(data, temp3);
```

or if you don't want the data object to change:

```
let data2 = Object.assign({}, data, temp3);
```

The spread operator can also be used, which basically is the same, just that the original data object doesn't change:

```
data = { ...data, ...temp3 };
```

Comment: It's exactly what I found, I have known the `spread operator` but I didn't know exactly how to use. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

with `jQuery` you can use `$.extend()`

```js
let data = {
  weight: '',
  DOB: '',
  gender: '',
}
let temp1 = {
   weight: '19.2',
}

console.log($.extend(data,temp1))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

OR use javascript spread operator `...` as following

```js
let data = {
  weight: '',
  DOB: '',
  gender: '',
}

let temp3 = {
   DOB: '1992-11',
   gender: 'Male',
}

data={...data,...temp3}
console.log(data)
```

If the keys are same then the value from righmost object is used